# Why does Firefox refuse to navigate to this domain?

Tags: firefox, adblock, advertisements

I noticed some advertisments slipping through my ad blocker. I decided that I might be better off navigating to the domain of the ad provider, going to page settings and ban all permissions, including javascript and images.

The domain in the IFRAME that I found is `www.btserve.com`. However if I try to put it in address bar, Firefox erases it and replaces with the previous address. I can see in net panel, that the request was made, but I cannot access page permissions unless I'm on that site.

Why does firefox hide the ad domain from URL and refuses me from accessing it? How else can I block permissions for that domain?

Comment: Are you using uBlock Origin? You can block the domain with it without going to the page itself. Pretty sure that website is some kind of placeholder and the origin of the ad is somewhere else.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I'm not using that, but I'm intrigued. Can it block all connections to the ad domain? That would be probably much more useful than blocking urls and HTML elements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can but here is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) of uBlock Origin, there is a pretty good [wiki](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki) about everything it can do. I've never tried it myself as pretty much all ads get caught by it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does firefox hide the ad domain from URL and refuses me from accessing it?

The page returns the following HTTP response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 12:56:22 GMT
ETag: W/"a-bAsFyilMr4Ra1hIU5PyoyFRunpI"
Server: nginx/1.14.1
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

So there is nothing for Firefox to display and therefore Firefox goes back to a previous page that worked.

Since I am not an *AdBlock* user, I am unable to answer your second question. However, here is a workaround:

If you want to block all requests to a specific domain, you could add an entry to your `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` under *nix OS's or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` under Windows OS's), like the following:

```
127.0.0.1 btserve.com
```

This will redirect all requests for this domain to your own computer, which will silently discard them. Note that you will need administrator privileges to edit the `hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

After using the network tool on firefox, the response of the website contains these headers:

`HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 12:57:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.14.1
X-Frame-Options: DENY
ETag: W/"a-bAsFyilMr4Ra1hIU5PyoyFRunpI"`

And no content is attached.

The 204 error means that the resquest was received and understood by the server, but there is no data to return to the user.

source:
https://www.koozai.com/blog/analytics/server-response-codes-and-what-they-mean/#204